# Algorithms to Compute Dimension of Lie Algebra

Tags: algorithms, lie-algebras

I am looking for fast algorithms to solve the following problem:

Let $\{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_m\}\subseteq M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be an independent set over $\mathbb{R}$. Find the dimension of the real lie algebra generated by $\{b_1, b_2, \dots, b_m\}$.

I can think of a simple algorithm which relies on calculating the nested brackets, and this is bound to terminate as $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is finite-dimensional as a real vector space. Is there a better algorithm for this problem?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I will also appreciate any non trivial bound for performance of above algorithm. For example, the "depth" of nested brackets is trivially $O(n^2)$. Can we do better than this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez thanks for your input, but it is not quite what I am looking for. If relations in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are too hard to capture, then do you know of any special cases where this problem has a solution?

Comment: I would think it might be worthwhile to first check which of the generators are e.g. semisimple, or (simultaneously) diagonalizable or triangularizable. But I really don't know how that knowledge would speed up some algorithm in practice, except in trivial cases.

Comment: You may want to ping Alex Hulpke, this kind of computational algebra is his specialty. If he does not answer, Wilhelm de Graaf (who is not on MSE) would be a person to write to, or at least check his webpage.